# Actual flow of SP initiated SAML SSO that includes all the components ie IDP, SP client side and SP server side

Tags: angularjs, rest, single-sign-on, openid, saml-2.0

I am using **keycloak** as IDP, j**ersey rest services** as backend and **angular UI** as frontend where my backend and frontend are separate application running on the **same tomcat server**.

Every example I found on the internet uses complete backend for SP initiated SAML SSO. I don't understand where does frontend contribute or how is frontend protected.

As when we talk about open id SSO protocol I found out that user agent calls frontend application which redirects user to IDP and gets the code and passes it on to backend. Backend does all the validation of the tokens.

So I had some questions

1. Is the flow in SAML same as open id if we have a frontend application?
2. Can frontend application produce SAML request and redirect user to the IDP?
3. After successful authentication IDP redirects to backend or to frontend?
4. How are services protected and where is the SAML assertion validated?

Answer (score 1):

```
Is the flow in SAML same as open id if we have a frontend application?
```

more or less. User goes to front end application, is denied access as they don't have a valid session with the application.

```
Can frontend application produce SAML request and redirect user to the IDP?
```

yes. It would need to create a SAMLRequest containing an [AuthNRequest](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php) and POST it to the SP.

> After successful authentication IDP redirects to backend or to
> frontend?

more or less. The IdP checks the SP Attribute Consumer Service (ACS) url in the metadata first. If it doesn't match, it refuses to send the SAMLResponse to the SP.

```
How are services protected and where is the SAML assertion validated?
```

It's up to the SP. If the user doesn't have a valid session at the application, they need to be redirected to the IdP and the application must validate the SAMLResponse and create a valid session for the user based on the attributes in that response.

Validation is done via X509 certificates contained in SAML metadata. It's complex stuff though.

Comment: Any suggestion on what flow would be the most suitable? I was am planning to build SAML authentication request on client side (angular) and send it to IDP. IDP after successful authentication would send SAML response to ACS url which would be of SP where all the validation would take place. Is it the correct approach?

Comment: it would be difficult to build it on the client side as it may need to be signed using X509 certificate. SAML is normally done on the server